# Difference between the if statement and "?/:" operator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, if-statement

I have this piece of code here.  In `case ServiceType.Register:`  I have what appears to be two equivalent statements one using a regular `if` statement and one using the ternary operator `?/:`.  For the `if` statement VS reports no error.  However with this line:

`IsXML == true ? PopulateRegister(ParseType.Xml) : PopulateRegister(ParseType.Str);`

VS is erroring out saying:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Anyone know why regular `if` statement has no error but if you use "?/:" (one liner) throws an error?  Pic is also attached.

```
switch (this.ServiceType)
{
    case SerivceType.Login:
        PopulateLogin();
        break;
    case SerivceType.Register:

        if (IsXML == true)
            PopulateRegister(ParseType.Xml);
        else
            PopulateRegister(ParseType.Str);

        IsXML == true ? PopulateRegister(ParseType.Xml) : PopulateRegister(ParseType.Str);

        break;
    case SerivceType.Verify:
        PopulateVerify();
        break;
}
```

[image]

Comment: ?: is used for conditional ASSIGNMENT. The parts on the right must return a type, and then can be assigned to something

Comment: `    public void PopulateRegister(ParseType type)
        {`  return type is void

Comment: Correct, but `void` cannot be assigned to anything...you cannot create a new instance of the `Void` struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `?:` operator is used for conditional assignments, not operations.

The statement:

```
IsXML == true ? PopulateRegister(ParseType.Xml) : PopulateRegister(ParseType.Str);
```

would be valid if the method `PopulateRegister` returns a value, and if you assigned that value to something. For example, this would be valid:

```
string result = (someCondition) ? "condition is true" : "condition is false";
```

You might want to use the conditional this way instead (note that we are using the `ParseType` enum value as a return type of the condition, and it is acting as the parameter to your method):

```
PopulateRegister((IsXML) ? ParseType.Xml : ParseType.Str);
```

Note that the above is possible, but can produce hard to understand/debug/maintain code and would generally not be thought of as a best practice.

Comment: You get the green check mark because of your FAST response.  May you bear many sons and this year's crop be better than last year.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A conditional operator is a shortcut to assign a value to a variable. But your method `PopulateRegister` does not return a value(`void`). So use an `if-else` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is that `if..then..else` is a statement, meaning it is supposed NOT to return a value, think of it as if it was a void function of sorts (not really so, but i hope you get the idea) while the `? :` operator is an expression, meaning it returns a value and since the functions you are using are `void` there is nothing to return. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> IsXML == true ? PopulateRegister(ParseType.Xml) : PopulateRegister(ParseType.Str);

You are not assigning the result to anything.

> The conditional operator (?:) **returns** one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator. [Emphasis mine]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

There is nothing to return as your functions are of return type void.

Answer (score 1):

`if` is a *statement* and `?:` is a ternary *operator*, to be used within an *expression*. Its operands *must* be expressions yielding a value. Your method `PopulateRegister` doesn't return a value, so it won't work.

You cannot provide an arbitrary expression in place of a statement, so what you thought would be a shortcut won't work. The following is not a valid statement:

```
// this is an expression, not a statement
IsXML == true ? PopulateRegister(ParseType.Xml) : PopulateRegister(ParseType.Str);
```

This would be valid:

```
// this is a valid statement
PopulateRegister(IsXML ? ParseType.Xml : ParseType.Str);
```

---

Side notes:

- Don't use `IsXML == true` — `IsXML` is a boolean expression itself, so an equality comparison to `true` is completely redundant and just clutters your code.
- The error you are observing is compile-time. Hence it is *not thrown* by the code itself, it's reported by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the block: `(b) ? (c) : (d)` as a one stand-alone object **value**. Such that `b` is boolean. `c` and `d` are inherited from `object`.